# Use express.static to serve per-user content

Tags: node.js, express

I want to set up an Express route to serve static content, from a directory which depends on the user. Authentication is per session; logged-in users have their ID stored as `req.session.user_id`. For these users, I want to serve the user's private static content, which is stored at `__dirname + '/private/' + req.session.user_id`. This is my best attempt, which doesn't work:

```
app.use('/static', function (req, res) {
    if (res.session.user_id != undefined) {
        // this is wrong
        express.static(__dirname + '/private/' + req.session.user_id);
    } 
});
```

What's the easiest way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to have a dynamic process to find the files to serve, this is not static anymore and it's nonsense to try to use the `static` method for this.

Your best shot is something like this :

```
app.use('/static*', function (req, res) {
    if (res.session.user_id != undefined) {
        var url = req.url.replace('/static', '');

        // Serve the asked file directly
        fs.createReadStream(__dirname + ' /private' + req.session.user_id + url).pipe(res);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Will this allow browser caching with etags?

Comment: I think it does not. You have to handle this yourself.